# alexa dynamic entities is not updated

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to build a simple skill that uses dynamic entities.
here is the link to source: [alexa dynamic entities test](https://github.com/fdistorted/alexa-dynamic-entities-test).
But somehow they are not updated.
It works when I choose static data:
[image: static]
And not works when I am trying to use dynamic:
[image: dynamic]

Comment: It might be easier work out what's happening if you share your voice interaction model (the JSON) for this intent.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove spaces from values of dynamic entities (e.g. "first one" change to "first")